# scrolling diagonal on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

***The Problem:***

I'm working on a project which requires a div to have a width > 100% on a mobile device (think of tablet).  On a typical desktop, having a width that large will blow out the body, and show scroll bars.  On mobile, it scales all of that down to fit inside the viewport. As a result I've wrapped this large div in a containing div with 'overflow:scroll' set.  This works  as expected so that I can drag the element around.  However, in doing so, I can only scroll on the X and Y, not on a diagonal.

Currently, I'm not using any viewport meta tags, however I've tried the following:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

***TL;DR:***

I have code that looks like the following

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
  <div style="width:400%"></div>
</div>
```

and I can only scroll on the X or Y, not diagonal.

*EDIT*: added JS as a tag because I'm not opposed to a JS solution, although I'd prefer something which is light weight.

Comment: Which device and browser?

Comment: I've done testing on chrome (motorola Xoom 4.1.2) and ipad IOS 7 Safari